# Remove spinner on number type paper-input in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, polymer, paper-elements, polymer-3.x

I would like to hide the number spinner on [paper-input](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input) 3.x in all browsers. I'm currently struggling to hide it on just Firefox.

The solution described at the top [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/279) works on Chrome, but `-moz-appearance: textfield` does not affect the inside `<input>` element. I just adds an outline to the `<paper-input>` element.

```
return html`
    <style>
      paper-input {
        --paper-input-container-input-webkit-spinner: {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          margin: 0;
        }
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-input type="number" value="123"></paper-input>
`;
```

Results in: [image]

I also tried placing the `-moz-appearance` inside a mixin:

```
return html`
    <style>
      paper-input {
        --paper-input-container-input-webkit-spinner: {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          margin: 0;
        }
        --paper-input-container-shared-input-style: {
          -moz-appearance: textfield;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <paper-input type="number" value="123"></paper-input>
`;
```

Results in: [image]

I created a glitch page to demo it (JSBin/unpkg don't work for paper-input 3.0):
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/freckle-lilac

I'm not sure if I'm using the incorrect mixin, or if there's a simpler vanilla CSS way to fix this. The `type="number"` input is necessary for mobile platforms, but the spinner is not desirable for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of tinkering around, I was able to solve my own problem. It looks like `var(--paper-input-container-shared-input-style_-_-webkit-appearance)` is automatically set as the value for the `<input>`'s `-moz-appearance` on Firefox.

I was able to do this to remove the spinner on Chrome and Firefox, as well as fix the width issue that came up, too:

```
<style>
   paper-input {
     --paper-input-container-input-webkit-spinner: {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
     }
     --paper-input-container-shared-input-style: {
       width: 50px;
       -webkit-appearance: textfield;
     }
     width: 50px;
   }
</style>
```

Demo: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/zippy-crime

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom input styling with `paper-input-container` and `iron-input`,  but not `paper-input` here below example:

```
<paper-input-container>
       <div slot="prefix">Numbers ? :</div>
       <label slot="label">Your value..? </label>
       <iron-input slot="input" type="number" value="{{myValue}}">
          <input value="{{myValue::input}}" style="/*! outline: none; (not working)*/width: 100%;border-color: transparent;">
       </iron-input>
</paper-input-container>
```

[Demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/brief-table?path=index.html:45:32)